# Shell command to show most hits for given period

Tags: shell, server, count, ip

I want to show the IP's by hits on my server. I found the following that seems to do it:

```
    awk -vDate=`date -d'now-10 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $1}'  /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail
```

It displays something like

```
    3346 123.242.4.51
    14315 123.0.0.1
    35951 123.73.173.170
```

The problem is that it always shows that for the day. So if I run it at 8 AM and again at 8 PM, it will display the same thing. But if I run it the next day, it changes. I found the command I'm using here, I think, and it may not be correct. Would someone please show the correct command, assuming this is possible?

Comment: Could you add some lines of your log to your message? Knowing the content format is required design a script.

Comment: Do you really want statistics only for the last 10 minutes?

Comment: You can better use yyyy-mm-dd in your log format. Old lines from December 26 - 31  all satisfy the check `if ($4 > Date)`. Or do you have a new file every day?

Comment: It's a log on a live server so it's constantly updated. The load on the server might be 2 now but in 20 in an hour. I don't need it to run every 10 minutes but once an hour would be nice. The original code has "now 2 hours". I changed it to minutes to see if that would make a difference but it returns the same results no matter what is there. The log keeps recording until a size limit is reached. If I blocked some IP yesterday and it still shows up for today, then the report is useless since I don't know if the account is new or not, unless I manually check the firewall.

Comment: Try to find out what is going wrong. Something like `'$4 > Date '{print "field4=" $4 "in the line " $0; }'. You can also change your approach and remember the last line (`wc -l`)  you looked at.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't know code used in such commands. I'll search around some more and post a fix here if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sample log entries. For these entries, the script would show 3 hits on IP 678.138.147.158 and 2 on 127.0.0.1. Most of the IP's used here are not valid IP's, in case someone notices that.

```
    678.138.147.158 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:43:52 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
    665.73.173.170 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:44:18 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 163 "-" "check_http/v1.4.16 (nagios-plugins 1.4.16)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:45:01 -0500] "GET /whm-server-status HTTP/1.0" 200 50752 "-" "-"
    678.138.147.158 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:45:18 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 163 "-" "check_http/v1.4.16 (nagios-plugins 1.4.16)"
    150.244.199.72 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:45:57 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
    678.138.147.158 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:46:18 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 163 "-" "check_http/v1.4.16 (nagios-plugins 1.4.16)"
    127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2019:13:47:09 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" 400 10087 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Please add this to your question and remove the answer (including my comment ;-).